# Reading/Accessing to app settings value issue

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, app-config

Hello I'm trying to access this setting:
[image]

with following code:

```
string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["swPath"].ToString();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.Open(path,FileMode.Open));
```

But I get following exception:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

May I ask where do I make a mistake? Thank you so much for your time.

Update issue for Ehsan Ullah:

```
   Properties.Settings.Default.swPath = cestasouboru.Text;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

I think this isn't that helpful for you but how can I provide more helpful information?

Comment: Did you try to set the access modifier to public?

Comment: Hello Daniel, I think that it is not neccessary, if you are interested in solution please see Ehsan's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the way you are reading is for AppConfig. Whereas you are reading from the custom settings.

read it like this

```
string path = Properties.Settings.Default.swPath;
```

to save it

```
Properties.Settings.Default.swPath = "your path";
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Comment: Thank you Ehsan for your time and answers. You are an awesome person. Your codes works whenever I ask my trivial questions. May I ask for some reference how can I update this value in app settings from textbox? I mean it like this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18099910/storing-data-into-appconfig-from-textbox and Coder's answer. Thanks again.

Comment: @Marek do it the same way shown here - Properties.Settings.Default.swPath = "your path";

Comment: @Marek glad that i am of any help. see my updated answer for saving it.

Comment: @EhsanUllah I tried to update the swPath with this code but it didn't updated. I will post my code into answer, would you please help me with that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Marek did  you called save after that? see my complete answer

Comment: It might have been mistake, this is updating but in Settings.settings I still see the old one, where I can see updated one? Thank you

Comment: @Marek u i don't remember precisely but i think it was in temp or users folder

Comment: @EhsanUllah When I do this save will it be remembered even when to program is closed and then turned on again ?